# Is there any forward / redirection limit in exchange (2016)?

Tags: email, exchange

A customer needs a redirection like this:

Mail => user1@customer.xxx => user2@customer.xxx => user3@customer.xxx => user4@customer.xxx

The redirection works until `user3` but `user4` does not get the mail. When the mail is sent **directly** to `user2` then `user4` gets the mail. So there seems to be a redirction limit in exchange 2016 (it seems to be working till exchange 2010).

Is there any limit that can be increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are such limits, and they are even enforced across Exchange servers.

The Microsoft article
[Exchange Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits),
lists these limits in section
[Journal, Transport, and Inbox rule limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#journal-transport-and-inbox-rule-limits)
(bold emphasis is mine):

> **Number of times a message is redirected**
>
> The number of times a message will be redirected, forwarded, or
>   replied to automatically based on Inbox rules. For example, User A has
>   an Inbox rule that redirects messages to User B, based on the sender.
>   User B has an Inbox rule that forwards messages to User C based on
>   keywords in the subject line. If a message satisfies both of these
>   conditions, the message is only sent to User B; it's not forwarded to
>   User C because only one redirection is allowed. In this case, the
>   message is dropped without sending a non-delivery report (NDR) to User
>   B indicating that the message wasn't delivered to User C. **We make use
>   of the X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop header to determine the number
>   of times that a message was redirected. This header remains also
>   across Exchange organizational boundaries.**

There does not seem to be any way of modifying this limit.
You are already lucky that you can do two redirections,
since the documentation only specifies one.

The article
[Office 365 Exchange Online Plans (1 / 2 / Kiosk) Differences and Comparison](https://techjourney.net/office-365-exchange-online-plans-1-2-kiosk-differences-and-comparison/)
lists this same hard limit for all Office 365 plans
(although it dates from 3 years ago and things might have changed).

You may defeat this mechanism if you can find a way to delete
the `X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop` header from the email while redirecting,
but I'm afraid that I can't help you in that.